# AngularJS Not a function exception

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

Hello guys I am encountering a problem with an angular project. My project is an HTML page and I have the following JS code inside the `head` tags:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller = ('Data', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + my_var).success(function (response) {
        $scope.Movies = response.Search;
    });
});
```

and my relative content is shaped as following:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    ...
    <table id="search-results-container" ng-controller="Data">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="{{fetched.Poster}}" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="result-content">
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="movie-title"><h2>{{fetched.Title}}</h2></a>
                    <label>Year: {{fetched.Year}}</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and Im getting the following error at the Inspect Element console:

Error 1:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/user/path_to_page/%7B%7Bfetched.Poster%7D%7D  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Error 2:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ng/areq?p0=Data&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at angular.js:38
at sb (angular.js:1911)
at Qa (angular.js:1921)
at angular.js:10153
at $f (angular.js:9272)
at n (angular.js:9065)
at g (angular.js:8459)
at g (angular.js:8462)
at g (angular.js:8462)
at g (angular.js:8462)
```

I am totally new in AngularJS and I don't know what Im doing rong Ive been googling for 2 days now... I appreiciate any help thank you

Comment: Try `app.controller('Data', function ($scope, $http) {` rather than `app.controller = ('Data', function ($scope, $http) {`

Comment: Wow thanks @dan, that did some trick but now my data is returning blank... The json file has the following format:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=starwars

I tried setting it to `$scope.Movies = response` instead of `$scope.Movies = response.Search` but that didnt work either. I appreciate your help so much tho thank you

Comment: Oh and the first error still remains I dont understand why is it trying to get a file with the name `{{fetched.Poster}}` from my computer

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer which I think solves a few of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You use `<img src="{{fetched.Poster}}" alt="" />`. The browser sends automatically a get-request to retrieve the image. A better way is to use ng-src. It could look something like `<img ng-src="{{fetched.Poster}}" alt="" />` Here the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to the AngularJS documentation.

I can not find your declaration and initialisation of your variable fetched. As long as there is no valid url stored, the browser will still fail to retrieve the image.

In your a-tag you should not use onclick. Use ng-click directive instead.

Hope this answer does help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fetched poster is in your HTML: .
It looks like your trying to populate the image from the $http response.

Google a simple example?

Comment: if you add `console.log(response);` above `$scope.Movies = response.Search;` you can output the response and see what data is coming back. From there you can determine how you want to output it.

Comment: It looks like `response.Search` will have an array of objects. So you want to look for ng-repeat to probably output all these? This is a fairly simple example which should get you going: [https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this plunker if this is what you wanted:
https://plnkr.co/edit/S5AXFLCxD9unwAGo1THY?p=preview

It should be:

```
 $scope.Movies = response.data.Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you have a few minor issues.

Firstly, `app.controller = (` should be `app.controller(`

Secondly, the syntax around $http.get is slightly different. Check out [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Thirdly, in the HTML, you need to reference the variable name you apply to the $scope. I.e. `Movies`, rather than `fetched`.

Finally, because the API returns an array of result, you probably want to use `ng-repeat`.

Full example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('App', []);
            app.controller('Data', function ($scope, $http) {
                var my_var = "starwars"
                $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + my_var).then(function success(response) {
                    $scope.Movies = response.data.Search;
                }, function error(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <bodyy ng-app="App">
        <table id="search-results-container" ng-controller="Data">
            <tr ng-repeat="movie in Movies">
                <td>
                    <img ng-if="movie.Poster !== 'N/A'" ng-src="{{movie.Poster}}" alt="" />
                    <div ng-if="movie.Poster === 'N/A'">No poster</div> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="result-content">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="movie-title"><h2>{{movie.Title}}</h2></a>
                        <label>Year: {{movie.Year}}</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error you're seeing is because the API is returning N/A for the poster URL. You'll need some logic to handle this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're overriding the controller function, not calling it.

But you have other problems too:

1. my_var is never declared.
2. Check for the success in a `then` call, not `success` (that will fail ;)
3. Your returned data is under `response.data`, therefore you're looking for `response.data.Search`.

This is what you're looking for:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Data', function ($scope, $http) {
    var my_var = 'starwars'
    $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + my_var).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Movies = response.data.Search;
    });
});
```

Finally, you want to iterate the results, right? So not knowing what exactly `fetched` is supposed to be in your listing, I redefined it to match with my expectation.

Change your `<tr>` to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="fetched in Movies">
```

That will iterate Movies and assign fetched to the value of each iteration.